# Thumbnail Open Graph não aparece no Whatsapp

Tags: html5, whatsapp, thumbnail, html-meta-tag

No site https://www.institutomagnus.org/blog/instituto-magnus-no-programa-pet-patas-da-tv-sol-indaiatuba que estou dando manutenção fiz as modificações necessárias para atender o link abaixo. Mas nenhuma das opções apresentadas solucionou meu problema.

Rodei o Checker e os resultados estão em https://opengraphcheck.com/result.php?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.institutomagnus.org%2Fblog%2Finstituto-magnus-no-programa-pet-patas-da-tv-sol-indaiatuba#.XJOZtyJKiiM

Alguém pode me dar uma luz sobre o que pode estar acontecendo?

Este pode ser entendido como uma duplicação de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100917/showing-thumbnail-for-link-in-whatsapp-ogimage-meta-tag-doesnt-work#32154775

Comment: Tenta colocando sua imagem em 200px por 200px, e não 250. é só um teste simples mesmo, e tente deixa-la com menso de 50kb

Comment: Consegui o problema era que o site usava https e as imagens dentro do thumb estavam usando http.

Comment: Vc pode colocar seu comentario de como resolve em forma de Resposta e depois Aceita-la, ai fica como registro para outros

Comment: Valeu @hugocsl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema era que o site usava https e as imagens dentro do thumb estavam usando http.